# DocmdApplyFilter syntax errors

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access form I'm getting a

```
               Run-time error'3705:
```

Syntax error in date query expression '(( ( [Date of Purchase] >=##And[Date of urchase]<=##))'.

whenever I run my code that,without the Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo and Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo
fields being populated instead of the msg box that should run. In addition I get a "Enter Parameter Value" dialog box  popping up when I click the "Clear" button with or without data being displayed. In order to clear the form of data I have to hit the space bar  while in the input box of the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog box in order to clear the form. If I hit cancel I get a Run-time error 2501 "the ApplyFilter action was canceled and I'm taken to my code sheet with the "DoCmd.ApplyFilter task"  highlighted if I debug the error.

I have removed several portions of the code rechecked the spelling and spacing

```
Option Compare Database


 Private Sub CmdSearch_Click()
 'Search button

    Call Search
    End Sub
        Sub Search()
        Dim strCriteria, task As String

    Me.Refresh
If IsNull(Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom) Or IsNull(Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the date range", vbInformation, "Date Range 
Required"
    Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom.SetFocus
Else
    strCriteria = "([Date of Purchase] >= #" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom & "# 
And [Date of Purchase] <=#" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo & "#)"
    task = "select * From TblPurchases Where( " & strCriteria & ") order 
by [Date of Purchase] "
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
    'Me.TxtTotal = FindRecordCount

End If


End Sub

    Private Sub CmdClear_Click()

    Dim task As String

    Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom = ""
    Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo = ""
    task = "select * from TblPurchases where PrimaryKey is null"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter task

     'Me.TxtTotal = FindRecordCount



End Sub

    Private Sub CmdShowAll_Click()
Dim task As String

    Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom = ""
    Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo = ""
    task = "select * from TblPurchases order by [Date of Purchase] "
    Me.RecordSource = task
     'Me.TxtTotal = FindRecordCount

End Sub
```

I'm expecting that if I just cancel the dialog box the form should remain on screen.
Also if the "from" and "t/o" fields are empty I should get the MsgBox results.

i'm not sure what is the syntax error surrounding the "DoCmd.ApplyFilter task" 
What error am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria cannot be a full SQL sentence, only the criteria:

```
strCriteria = "[Date of Purchase] >= #" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateFrom & "# And [Date of Purchase] <= #" & Me.TxtPurchaseDateTo & "#"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter strCriteria
```

You can use *Nz* to avoid errors from empty textboxes:

```
strCriteria = "[Date of Purchase] >= #" & Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateFrom.Value, Date) & "# And [Date of Purchase] <= #" & Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateTo.Value, Date) & "#"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter strCriteria
```

Or:

```
If IsNull(Me!TxtPurchaseDateFrom.Value) Then
    strCriteria = "[Date of Purchase] <= #" & Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateTo.Value, Date) & "#"
Else
    strCriteria = "[Date of Purchase] >= #" & Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateFrom.Value, Date) & "# And [Date of Purchase] <= #" & Nz(Me!TxtPurchaseDateTo.Value, Date) & "#"
End If
DoCmd.ApplyFilter strCriteria
```

Comment: I still get a synax error, instead of the msgbox if no date range is set. With this  Ieverything works except that without a date range enter I get the error

Comment: Then modify the criteria to accept this. See edited answer, please.